# Unable to Close Twain Source

Tags: windows-10, vb6, twain

I have a customer who suddenly started getting Twain errors when trying to scan in my program.

The software was developed in 32-bit VB6 and uses BlackIce Image SDK, version 10.6.6, to handle scanning through Twain.

Over the last few weeks, this customer gets errors when trying to scan. It will sometimes successfully scan but shows an error afterwards:

> Unable to close twain source. Error code 7, Twain status 11

The customer is unable to make subsequent scans until she restarts my application.

Everything was working fine on this customer's environment until earlier this month (Windows update possibly). We have tried three different scanners and many times uninstalling/reinstalling the drivers, but nothing seems to change.

Any thoughts on what this error means or the best way to fix it?

The customer is using Windows 10, 64-Bit, Version 1909 (OS Build 18363.1198).